# How to take advantage of AWS lambda's multi-core processor using Node.js runtime?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, x86-64, arm64

AWS lambda `x86_64` and `arm64` architectures offer two processor cores. Node.js uses the single threaded event loop model.

**What strategies can be used to take advantage of both processor cores?**

You can get the number of processor cores using this lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const rspMsg = 'Number of CPU cores: ' + require('os').cpus().length;
    console.log(rspMsg);
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: rspMsg,
    };
};
```

Lambda function response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Number of CPU cores: 2\""
}
```

Comment: maybe something like https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options ?

Comment: Forking isn't the recommended solution. Check this article out for info on [worker_threads](https://blog.logrocket.com/node-js-multithreading-what-are-worker-threads-and-why-do-they-matter-48ab102f8b10/).